# Make a shared_ptr with only one owner

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have an object in C++11 that has only one owner. However, other objects can hold a `weak_ptr` to this object. This way, I can test if the object still exists before I use it.

For now, the owner has a `shared_ptr` to the object, that always has an owner count of 1.

How to ensure no one is allowed to make a copy of this `shared_ptr`?

I can't use a `unique_ptr` because apparently C++11 does not allow to make a `weak_ptr` out of a `unique_ptr`.

**EDIT** : Thank you for your replies !

All the program runs on a single thread. The main owner has a periodical update loop, in which it calls all of its subsystems.

Thanks for pointing out that using a `weak_ptr` actually creates a `shared_ptr`. The expectation is that no subsystem or object is allowed to store a `shared_ptr` during a call to another non-const function. This way, any function can ask the owner to remove an object from its collection, and the object is deleted immediately.

I was hoping to avoid the overhead of increasing the ref count of the `shared_ptr` each time a subsystem calls `lock()`, since it is expected to release the ownership immediately (and ensure it is the case at compile time.)

**EDIT 2** : Example code to formulate my problem more clearly

```
class Manager {
  public:
    Manager();           //Creates objects and stuff
    void updateAllObjects() {
      for (auto& o : mObjects)
        o->update(*this);
    }
    void deleteObject(weak_ptr<WorldObject>);    //May be called by other objects
    vector<shared_ptr<WorldObject>> mObjects;
};

class WorldObject {
  public:
    virtual void update(Manager&)=0;
};

class Passenger : public WorldObject {
  public:
    void update(Manager&);
};

class Car : public WorldObject {
  public:
    void update(Manager&);    //May call Manager::deleteObject on its passengers, or change them etc...
    //If Manager decides to delete passenger, they must be destroyed, so we don't want those references to count
    vector<weak_ptr<Passenger>> mPassengers;
    //A passenger can belong to several cars, and must be updated exactly once per WorldObject::update()
};
```

How to :
- Avoid the overhead of storing many `shared_ptr`
- Make sure `Car` does not store a `shared_ptr` to a passenger for longer than its `Car::update()` function

Comment: Use `unique_ptr` to denote an owner and raw pointer instead of `weak_ptr` to denote users

Comment: [Pointer Zen and Fengshui](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)

Comment: @Drop: The whole point of his use of `weak_ptr` is so that the users can know when the pointer has been destroyed. A raw pointer can't know that. His use case is that he wants to use ownership semantics to transmit information to users about when the pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think "The way" is to have a `unique_ptr` owner and just not to call users when owner releases it. Practice shows it's possible. In this case, there is no need to validate weak pointer or anything at all. Again, it is what language gurus teach us now in CppCoreGuidelines. `shared_ptr` + `weak_ptr` schema is just another way to produce a latent memory leak. It is also no better than a  global variable. In poorly designed programs they migrate from one place to another and never go away. The era of shared ownership is over (As Herb Sutter sometimes says, "we were young and stupid")

Comment: What do you mean "not to call users when owner releases it" ?

Comment: @Mathers Well, as your resources are in the container, just don't call the user (the guy with weak/raw pointer) in the next iteration of the loop if the resource is gone. Or call it with other resources, but don't give them the pointer to one that is invalid. My point is: owner decides what to share, not user. I think you shouldn't store any pointers at all in the user. We need to see some code to be sure.

Comment: The discussion comes extremely closely to the opinionated holy war and theoretical speachmaking. I think you should post a clearer problem description with the code to get some meaningful help.

Comment: @Drop Done ! Hope it clarifies my problem

Comment: Your `o.update();` doesn't work on two fronts: 1) o is a `shared_ptr<WorldObject>&`, it needs dereferencing.  And 2) you haven't passed `*this` to the invocation of `o.update()`.

Answer (score 5):

> For now, the owner has a shared_ptr to the object, that always has an
>   owner count of 1.

This is a false statement, as owner of `std::weak_ptr` only can use it by creating `std::shared_ptr` to it so owner count will be > 1. So your question is pretty much meaningless - if you want to provide only exclusive access to the object move `std::unique_ptr` around, if you want to use it through `std::weak_ptr` it must be shared and you cannot enforce single owner in principle.

Comment: This. And my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the nature of the `shared_ptr` is that you can create more instances of it. 
What you can do, is to make it a private member of the class, and don't expose the `shared_ptr` to the external world directly, as you do now.
You can't however be safe against a dumb used, someone could as well get a `weak_ptr`, extract the raw pointer and delete it. If the user of yoru class wants to shoot himself in the foot, there's nothing you can do!

Comment: you can still get a shared_ptr by using [lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) on the weak_ptr you exposed

Comment: +1 for pointing out that any measure taken relies on clients of your code base respecting contractual rules.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios (note to OP:) This is by design. weak_ptr providing safe access to a resource relies on extending the lifetime of said resource by temporarily increasing the circle of shared owners.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without implementing your own `valid_ptr` or something similar since you can always get another shared_ptr via [weak_ptr::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock). That is, only if you want to periodically check whether the object was deleted (i.e. not for checking if the object still exists or actually accessing it, see below!)

```
template<typename T>
class valid_ptr {
public:
     template<typename S>
     valid_ptr(const std::weak_ptr<S>& r) : m_ptr(r) { }
     bool expired() const { return m_ptr.expired(); }
private:
     std::weak_ptr<T> m_ptr;
};
```

If you actually want to access your pointer then you should simply use the weak_ptr how it is intended and aquire a shared_ptr for the duration of the access via `weak_ptr::lock`:

```
if (auto shared = weak.lock()) {
    // ptr is valid and can now be used via the shared_ptr shared
} else {
    // ptr is nullptr
}
```

You shouldn't simply rely on a positive `expired` check to access the object since between the check and the access anything can happen (including the object being deleted, unless you've got some additional constraints you didn't mention in your question). In that case you want to ensure (shared) ownership by acquiring a shared_ptr for the duration of the access.

Comment: Note that this implementation is not safe in a multi-threaded application. The resource can expire right after the call to expire() and before its use.

Comment: @denniskb I didn't think it was meant to be accessed (as I didn't expose the ptr in the `valid_ptr`) - I added a section to address this

Comment: Unfortunately, as soon as you create the shared_ptr you have defeated the requirements. This task is impossible with shared_ptr by virtue of the fact that you must make a shared_ptr to safely access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

If you must:

Use a shared ptr to a mutex locking functor containing a wraping a writable unique ptr.

Everyone else gets a shared ptr to a mutex wrapping functor wrapping a possibly null immutable raw ptr, implemented by wrapping the above and exposing the `.get()` result in `apply`.

The owner functor is owned by one bit of code.  It exposes the non-owner functors.  It can destroy the unique ptr.

Non-owner functors cannot extend the lifetime of the object past their mutex lock.

Owner functors can set the unique ptr to nothing, and (once they have the mutex) nobody can stop them.

You could use shared mutexes to allow multiple readers.

What do I mean by functor?

A functor is a type that wraps another type that supports apply.  If `[T]` is the functor type, and `T` the type wrapped, and `T->U` is the type of a function taking `T` and returning `U`, then the apply operation is of type:

```
([T],(T->U))->U
```

Or

```
[T].apply(T->U)
```

Returns a `U`.

If `T` is a type, you apply `T->U` to `T` to get `U`.

If `[T]` is a functor of `T`, then you apply it to `T->U` to get `U`.  (Notice the slight change in wording compared to previous paragraph).

A functor of `T` knows how to run functions of `T`, but makes no claim to *be* a `T`.

Implementation wise, it either contains a `T` or knows how to get one when asked.  It can make other guarantees about *how* it runs the functions (for example, guarded with a mutex, in a dedicated thread, on a server, whatever).

See Haskell for further information.

Also note that reentrancy cannot be supported with reasonable axioms, so deadlock on a single thread is possible.

This answer is not easy to understand: I am merely including it for completeness.  Unless you came to C++ from a modern functional programming background, anyone asking the OP's question probably won't get this, and shouldn't try (I am merely trying to show the OP's request is *possible*, nkt that it is a good idea).  What is worse is that I may have gotten some of the functional programming terminology wrong, if not the design.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a **std::unique_ptr** to the object and instead of **std::weak_ptr** a raw pointer to this **std::unique_ptr**. This way you have only one owner to the object and you can test the validity of the **std::unique_ptr** through the raw pointer to it using the bool operator.

```
auto object = std::make_unique<T>(...); // creates object and std::unique_ptr
...
auto* object_user = &object; // raw pointer to the std::unique_ptr holding the object
...
if ( *object_user ) (*object_user)->... // using the object
```

Note: The ellipses are any code you need.

Comment: Isn't dereferencing a pointer after its target was destroyed undefined behavior ?
Once the unique_ptr goes out of scope, the pointers to it cannot be dereferenced anymore, even to call its bool operator.

Comment: The object being owned by the std::unique_ptr may not exist. This is tested by "if (*object_user)". Of course, the std::unique_ptr itself must exist as long there are any references by "object_user"s.